# How to use letters in accusative?

Tags: accusative

In my math book, it describes "the projection of b onto a." Esperanto translates "onto" as "en" + an o-word in the accusative. This effect on consonants is obvious because they end in -o when pronounced (b: "bon", c: 
"con", d: "don"). But what about vowels? Is a pronounced "an" or "a-on"? Is o pronounced "on" or "o-on"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this section of PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/oa-vortecaj_vortetoj/liternomoj.html) mainly answers your question. So you can write *la projekcio de b sur/en a-on*. Like PMEG suggests, the *o* of consonant names are generally not considered to be an actual *o*-ending. Therefore, you'd write either *b-on* (say “bó-on”, not “bon”), *b-oj*, and *b-ojn*; or *boon*, *booj*, and *boojn*. Similarly, for vowels you'd get *a-on* or *aon*, *oon*/*o-on* etc.
Alternatively, you can leave out the ending entirely (PMEG gives examples like *du B* instead of *du B-oj*), but in certain mathematical contexts this is confusing: *A entenas B*. Is that A⊆B or B⊆A? So *A entenas B-on* is clear and standard (when pronounced *bo-on*).